# How to interpret nested interactions?

Tags: r, interaction, interpretation, regression-coefficients

Consider a data set where you have a `tenure` variable that takes non-negative values (e.g. from `0` to `44`) and a `tenurel` dummy that is `FALSE` when `tenure` is `0` and `TRUE` otherwise. How do you interepret their coefficients when both are included in a linear regression?

Take this example (originally from Wooldridge 2008):

```
library(foreign);library(lmtest)
wage1 <- read.dta("http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/wage1.dta")
wage1$tenurel <- as.logical(wage1$tenure)

coeftest(fitnestint <- lm(log(wage) ~ educ+exper+tenurel+tenure, data=wage1))
## 
## t test of coefficients:
## 
##              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept) 0.2757858  0.1042105  2.6464  0.008381 ** 
## educ        0.0899010  0.0074526 12.0630 < 2.2e-16 ***
## exper       0.0038215  0.0017323  2.2060  0.027819 *  
## tenurelTRUE 0.0732658  0.0480708  1.5241  0.128084    
## tenure      0.0200777  0.0033542  5.9859 4.008e-09 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**Question:** So how do you interpret the coefficients for `tenurel` (`0.073`) and `tenure` (`0.020`)?

---

In my understanding `tenurel` would represent the effect on Y of "having some tenure when `tenure=0`" (even if its literal interpretation would seem nonsensical, as it can happen for main-effect regressors in usual interactions) and `tenure` would represent the *additional* effect on Y "of one more year of tenure".

It seems to me that in this specification `tenure` is a "nested interaction", insofar as if we add an interaction term between the two regressors, it would be undefined:

```
coef(fitint <- lm(log(wage)~educ+exper+tenurel*tenure, data=wage1))
##        (Intercept)               educ              exper 
##        0.275785819        0.089900995        0.003821454 
##        tenurelTRUE             tenure tenurelTRUE:tenure 
##        0.073265829        0.020077744                 NA
```

Indeed, the interaction term `tenurel:tenure` would be identical to `tenure`:

```
with(wage1, all.equal(tenure, tenurel*tenure))  ##interaction term identical to tenure
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. I'd prefer not to have both tenure variables in as main effects, either. Instead, a spline of the teniure variable would be good, to capture nonlinear effects. Alternatively you could stratify and run a model for tenure = 0 and another for tenure =1

Comment: @PeterFlom Great to know my intuitions are correct. However, why do you invoke "nonlinear effects" in this case?

Comment: One reason to include the yes/no variable is to look for sharp changes between 0 and 1 in the numeric variable.

Comment: @PeterFlom But how do you detect if there is a sharp jump between 0 and 1 in the numeric variable? In the example here `tenurelTRUE` indicates if there is a jump *only* for `tenure=0` (which again by itself makes no sense). To detect the sharp change is it necessary to do a linear hypothesis test of some sort? Say `linearHypothesis(fitnestint, "tenurelTRUE + tenure", verbose=T)`...

Comment: I don't think I understand.

Comment: @PeterFlom Sorry, I guess I'm not very clear. You've suggested that this specification is useful to capture non-linear effects. But I'm not sure I understand why. When you say that the yes/no variable (`tenurel`) is used to *look for sharp changes between 0 and 1 in the numeric variable*, how can I spot this in the printed output? Which coefficient will show this?

Comment: Tenure1 seems like a bad attempt to measure this. Because, beyond tenure = 1 it makes no sense (what is the effect of an additional year of tenure when you don't have tenure?) it must be intended to measure the jump from 0 to 1.